# How is morphed skill mastery affected by a reset?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

Say a player morphs *Soul Trap* into *Consuming Trap* which is then leveled further. If the character resets their skills, then spends points to morph the spell into *Soul Spitting Trap*, does it get benefits of the prior alternate path? What about if the points were put into *Consuming Trap* again?

Comment: would you be able to cast a spell that you no longer had any points in what so ever?

Comment: No, but my understanding is if you reset and then re-added a point then you wouldn't need to level up the skill again. I don't know if that applies to morphed skills however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I morphed the Sorcerer spell *Crystal Shard* into *Crystal Fragments* and leveled it partially. Then, I reset that morph and switched to using *Crystal Blast* which started with an empty xp bar. After some more adventuring, I again reset Crystal Blast and switched back to Crystal Fragments morph, which restored the skill xp bar to the previous level before resetting Fragments.

This mean that skill mastery in ESO is **tracked independently for each morph and maintained** if you reset & later choose the morph again.